# Don't show blank record on autocomplete in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

I have this autocomplete in Angular

```
<input type="text" matInput [ngModel]="List" #searchInput [matAutocomplete]="autocopmlete" (focus)="filter('')"
      (ngModelChange)="filter($event)">
    <mat-autocomplete #autocopmlete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="Name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredObject" [value]="item" (onSelectionChange)="selectUser($event,item)"
        (click)="searchInput.value=''">
        {{ item.Name }} 
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

we use this filter function

```
 filter(value = '') {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || typeof value === 'undefined' || typeof this.chatList==='undefined') {
        return;
    }
    this.filteredObject = this.chatList.filter(
        a => ~a.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    );
  }
```

but issue is if i get those records also where `Name` is blank how should i remove that blank record from result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add an additional check in the `filter` function, where you can check if `Name` property exist on object `!!a.Name`

```
this.filteredObject = this.chatList.filter(
    a => (
      !!a.Name &&
      ~a.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase())
    )
);
```